# GIT repository from exported SVN

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have exported tar.gz file from SVN. How can I create GIT repo from this?

Answer (score 1):

Untar the archive somewhere, and then use git-svn to create a git repository from it.

I.e.

```
cd /tmp
tar xvzf repo.tar.gz

cd /home/me
git-svn clone file:///tmp/repo
```

If it's a standard svn layout, you can import the branches with

```
cd /home/me
git-svn clone -stdlayout file:///tmp/repo
```

If you created the archive to enable yourself to create a git repo from it - it might be easier to just point at your existing svn repository.

Comment: I do it on Windows 7. When I try the first snippet I get: "Initialized empty Git repository in c:/svn/git/.git/
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/git' at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1777"

Comment: This time: "Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Local URL 'file://svn' contains only a hostname"

Comment: Ah, tripple '/'. Ok. Now something like this: "svn-remote.svn.url already set: file://svn
wanted to set to: file:///svn"

Comment: what I wrote in console: "git svn clone file:///repo git". What I get: "Couldn't open a repository: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Unable to open repository 'file:///repo'" Am I doing something wrong?